# Can't post back JavaScript changes to ASP.NET ListBox option properties/attributes

Tags: javascript, asp.net, properties, listbox, postback

I'm trying to use JavaScript to change properties or attributes of an ASP.NET ListBox's options, but the only changes that the server sees on postback (asp:Button click) are the selected state of the options.  I'm ultimately trying to convey that the SS code should ignore certain selected options, and I was hoping I could use something simple like noting its hidden state, setting the option's disabled property, or adding an attribute.  The control, and some failed JS lines:

```html
<asp:ListBox ID="lstFacilities" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple" Height="200" />
```

```
//lbxFacs returned by document.getElementById
lbxFacs.options[f].style.display = 'none';
lbxFacs.options[f].disabled = true;
lbxFacs.options[f].setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
```

I hide them from view after selecting a filter from another control, and that works from the UI standpoint, but the server seems to have no way of knowing they're hidden.  I try to disable them, but the Enabled property is always true.  Adding attributes is useless too; the Attributes collection is always empty.  Server-side snippet:

```
    bool allSelected = lstFacilities.Items[0].Selected;  //"All Facilities", only want visible options

    foreach (ListItem option in lstFacilities.Items)
    {
        var optAtts = option.Attributes;  //Always empty

        if ((allSelected || option.Selected) && option.Value != "All" && option.Enabled)
            selectedFacsIDs += "," + facID;  //Always gets here when only "All" selected and some options invisible
    }
```

I can't even get changes to the options' text or values to come in SS.  I've also tried the jQuery equivalents.  Is there any way to rectify this, or will I have to invoke my proven backup plan of having the JS set the value of a hidden input for the server to read which options are valid?  Thanks...

Comment: When you post back to the server, the only thing you are transmitting are the *values* of the controls in your form, and the view state (which is encoded in a hidden field, and contains, among other things, your original dropdown values).  If you change the attributes of dropdown values in the form, it will not be sent back to the server.  This has nothing to do with ASP.NET, it's how form submission works in general.

Comment: So, only the original list item values come back, I can't even change those?